# Function for defining vector doesn't work in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell

I'm beginner in Haskell (currently learning pattern matching) and I tried to write simple function for defining vector:

```
vector :: (Num a) => a -> a -> String
vector 0 0 = "This vector has 0 magnitude."
vector x y = "This vector has a magnitude of " ++ show(sqrt(x^2 + y^2)) ++ "."
```

But I get bunch of errors which I don't understand at all.

```
helloworld.hs:9:8: error:
    • Could not deduce (Eq a) arising from the literal ‘0’
      from the context: Num a
        bound by the type signature for:
                   vector :: Num a => a -> a -> String
        at helloworld.hs:8:1-37
      Possible fix:
        add (Eq a) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            vector :: Num a => a -> a -> String
    • In the pattern: 0
      In an equation for ‘vector’:
          vector 0 0 = "This vector has 0 magnitude."

helloworld.hs:10:51: error:
    • Could not deduce (Show a) arising from a use of ‘show’
      from the context: Num a
        bound by the type signature for:
                   vector :: Num a => a -> a -> String
        at helloworld.hs:8:1-37
      Possible fix:
        add (Show a) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            vector :: Num a => a -> a -> String
    • In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely
        ‘show (sqrt (x ^ 2 + y ^ 2))’
      In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely
        ‘show (sqrt (x ^ 2 + y ^ 2)) ++ "."’
      In the expression:
        "This vector has a magnitude of "
        ++ show (sqrt (x ^ 2 + y ^ 2)) ++ "."

helloworld.hs:10:56: error:
    • Could not deduce (Floating a) arising from a use of ‘sqrt’
      from the context: Num a
        bound by the type signature for:
                   vector :: Num a => a -> a -> String
        at helloworld.hs:8:1-37
      Possible fix:
        add (Floating a) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            vector :: Num a => a -> a -> String
    • In the first argument of ‘show’, namely ‘(sqrt (x ^ 2 + y ^ 2))’
      In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely
        ‘show (sqrt (x ^ 2 + y ^ 2))’
      In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely
        ‘show (sqrt (x ^ 2 + y ^ 2)) ++ "."’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
Prelude> :load helloworld
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( helloworld.hs, interpreted )

helloworld.hs:10:51: error:
    • Could not deduce (Show a) arising from a use of ‘show’
      from the context: Integral a
        bound by the type signature for:
                   vector :: Integral a => a -> a -> String
        at helloworld.hs:8:1-42
      Possible fix:
        add (Show a) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            vector :: Integral a => a -> a -> String
    • In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely
        ‘show (sqrt (x ^ 2 + y ^ 2))’
      In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely
        ‘show (sqrt (x ^ 2 + y ^ 2)) ++ "."’
      In the expression:
        "This vector has a magnitude of "
        ++ show (sqrt (x ^ 2 + y ^ 2)) ++ "."

helloworld.hs:10:56: error:
    • Could not deduce (Floating a) arising from a use of ‘sqrt’
      from the context: Integral a
        bound by the type signature for:
                   vector :: Integral a => a -> a -> String
        at helloworld.hs:8:1-42
      Possible fix:
        add (Floating a) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            vector :: Integral a => a -> a -> String
    • In the first argument of ‘show’, namely ‘(sqrt (x ^ 2 + y ^ 2))’
      In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely
        ‘show (sqrt (x ^ 2 + y ^ 2))’
      In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely
        ‘show (sqrt (x ^ 2 + y ^ 2)) ++ "."’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Can somebody explain me how to write this function properly, at least what's wrong with `vector 0 0`?

Comment: Hint: `:t sqrt` and `:t show`.

Comment: Did you try the possible fix suggested by the error...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error messages tell you everything you need to know.

```
Could not deduce (Eq a)
```

When you use a pattern-match on a numeric literal, it needs the constraints `(Eq a, Num a)` because Haskell uses `==` internally to do matching on literals.

```
Could not deduce (Show a)
```

When you use `show`, you need the constraint `(Show a)`, because not all types are showable by default.

```
Could not deduce (Floating a)
```

When you use fractional operations such as `sqrt`, you need the constraint `(Floating a)`, because not all numeric types support these operations.

Putting it all together:

```
vector :: (Eq a, Num a, Show a, Floating a) => a -> a -> String
vector 0 0 = "This vector has 0 magnitude."
vector x y = "This vector has a magnitude of " ++ show(sqrt(x^2 + y^2)) ++ "."
```

You could also leave off the type signature, then ask ghci:

```
> let vector 0 0 = "This vector has 0 magnitude."; vector x y = "This vector has a magnitude of " ++ show(sqrt(x^2 + y^2)) ++ "."
> :t vector
vector :: (Eq a, Floating a, Show a) => a -> a -> [Char]
```

And here you can see that you don’t need the extra `Num a` constraint, because `Floating` is a subclass of `Num`, by way of `Fractional`. You can get information on these classes in ghci as well:

```
> :info Floating
class Fractional a => Floating a where
  pi :: a
  exp :: a -> a
  log :: a -> a
  sqrt :: a -> a
  ...
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
instance Floating Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
instance Floating Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
```

When writing very generic code like this, you generally have to specify all the constraints you use. But you could also give this function a simpler non-generic type such as `Double -> Double -> String`.

Answer (score 6):

The first type error is because you're pattern matching on the literal `0`. You've only required `Num a` where you needed `(Num a, Eq a)` in order for this to be possible.

The second type error is because you've tried to use show on a computation involving your `a`. So now, you need `(Num a, Eq a, Show a)`.

The third, because you've used sqrt, which does not reside in `Num` but in `Floating`, so now it's `(Num a, Eq a, Show a, Floating a)`.

Alternatively, you could have just removed the type signature entirely and prompted ghci for the type:

```
λ> :t vector
vector :: (Show a, Floating a, Eq a) => a -> a -> [Char]
```

Note that `Floating` implies `Num`.

Comment: I understand everything except the first one; author made a function for factorial without ``Eq a`` and it worked:
`factorial :: (Num a) => a -> String
factorial 0 = 1
factorial n = n * factorial (n - 1)`
How this works?

Comment: @Nikola I'm pretty sure that factorial definition would fail in a number of ways, including the same missing `Eq`.

Comment: @smarx You're right, author was using ``Integral`` instead of ``Num`` - my mistake!